# I cannot read a file because I receive "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode" error

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a file and want to convert it to utf8 encoding.

When I want to read, I receive this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 947: invalid continuation byte
```

My purpose was to read it and then convert it to utf8 encoding format, but it doesn't allow reading.

Here is my code:

```
#convert all files into utf_8 format
import os
import io
path_directory="some path string"
directory = os.fsencode(path_directory)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    file_name=os.fsdecode(file)
    file_path_source=path_directory+file_name
    file_path_dest="some address to destination file"
    with open(file_path_source,"r") as f1:
        text=f1.read()
    with io.open(file_path_dest,"w+",encoding='utf8') as f2:
        f2.write(text)
    file_path=""
    file_name=""
    text=None
```

and the error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-59e5e52ddd40> in <module>()
     10     with open(file_path,"r") as f1:
     11         print(type(f1))
---> 12         text=f1.read()
     13     with io.open(file_path.replace("ref_sum","ref_sum_utf_8"),"w+",encoding='utf8') as f2:
     14         f2.write(text)

/home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 947: invalid continuation byte
```

how can I convert my files to utf8 without reading them?

Comment: This pops up so often it's become hard to search for just because it gets too many hits. You're telling Python it's *already* utf-8, and that's not true, so decoding it fails.

Comment: Does file contain a utf header. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @0decimal0 No, it doesn't.

Comment: Put it there at the top and then try reading the file.

Comment: @YannVernier I don't know where i am telling this to python. how can i tell Python that i don't know the encoding format of this file?

Comment: @0decimal0 I add the header to my file but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @mahsa If you don't know the encoding of the file then its a big problem, you have provided the encoding but it still doesn't read it which means it is not encoded in utf , and if you don't know which encoding it is in , then its pretty difficult to read the file.

Comment: @0decimal0 I detect the formatting by chardet: it was 'ISO-8859-1'

Comment: Just a heads up, chardet guessing ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin-1) doesn't mean that is the encoding. That set is full 8-bit and might be guessed for arbitrary data; it's also extremely similar to some others, such as latin-9.

Comment: What ever encoding you get , you write it like `io.open(file_path_dest,"w+",encoding='ISO-8859-1')` by the way you should have posted it .

Comment: Did you try to open the file like the way I suggested ? you should mention the encoding .

Comment: @0decimal0 Yes that's right. It was a great help. Thankful. I changed a piece of code to this and the problem was resolved: 
    raw_data=open(file_path)
    rawdata_encoding=chardet.detect(rawdata)
    with io.open(file_path,"r",encoding=rawdata_encoding['encoding']) as f1:
        text=f1.read()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is obvious . If you want to open a file and its not **utf8** for python3(***utf8*** is default encoding for python3 and **ascii** for python2) then you have to mention the encoding you know the file is in while opening it :

```
io.open(file_path_dest,"r",encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

In this case encoding is **ISO-8859-1** so you have to mention it.

Comment: UTF-8 is the default encoding in Python 3 **only** when decoding byte strings. The `open` command, however, uses your locale, so on a Windows box it'll be your 8-bit code page. On Mac and modern Linux, it's likely to be UTF-8